# Executable with py2exe without incurring the [WinError87]

Tags: python, qt, py2exe

I made a simple interface using **PyQt** and now I'm trying to deliver an executable using **py2exe**.

The following `setup.py` script works fine:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['main.py'], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip"]}})
```

but when I use `windows=[]` instead of `console=[]` I get the error: `[WinError87] The parameter is incorrect`.

Is there an easy solution to this problem so I don't have to use the console.

*By the way I'm running py2exe version 0.9.2.2, Python 3.4, Python User Interface Compiler 4.11.3 for Qt version 4.8.6.*

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save your main file as  `main.pyw` and py2exe will automatically hide de console.

Comment: Thanks for answering... I tried but the console is still there, behind the Main Window

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setup(windows=['main.py'], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip"]}})
```

If not. Do like cdonts said. rename main.py to main.pyw.
.pyw indicates it should be interpreted by pythonw.exe and not python.exe. Which prevents commandline window popping up.